# Mat-select Control read by <HTMLInputElement>myForm.elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-material, angular6

**Hi I have a dynamic form where am not able to use formcontrolname to read value 
so I want to read value by element control ID**

currently i am reading value like this if is normal cantrol like (input button select and all)

```
let myForm = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById("userData");
    console.log(myForm.elements);  

<HTMLInputElement>myForm.elements[i]).getAttribute("id")
```

**But i when i reading mat-select which not html control so i am not able to read values**

```
<div *ngFor="let element of currentTaskJson" class="form-group">

 <!-- Input Tag Start Here -->
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngIf="element.controlName == 'input' && element.htmlControlTypeName !='file'">
              <input matInput type='{{element.htmlControlTypeName}}' [required]='element.required' max="16" id='{{element.labelID}}' placeholder={{element.labelName}}
              />
            </mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field 
  class="example-full-width" 
  *ngIf="element.controlName==='select'">
    <mat-select 
      placeholder={{element.labelName}} 
      (click)=getDropDownValue(element) 
      id='{{element.labelID}}'>
        <mat-option 
          *ngFor="let element3 of listObj[element.labelID]" 
          value={{element3.id}}>
            {{element3.value}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

***currentTaskJson this a array that contains 3 input type filed 2 select that i printing form here***

**so this input control prints 3 times so i am using any formcontrolname here that will be same for all 3 
by Id i getting form backend in this JSON aray i a want by ID**

Comment: hello @krishna do you have idea how i can do that

Comment: Why are you not trying to figure out why you're not able to use formControlName to read the value?

Comment: Because i have dynmic control that display form i json array and i con't set static value and i can't user some formcontrol name for more then one fields

Comment: this.exampleForm = this._fb.group({
    companyName: ['']
  });

Is there any way i can used this campany name from a json  or dynamically as

Comment: finally able to achieve this  thanks to all